# DevTools failed to load sourcemap problem: Could not load content

Tags: python, django, static, django-templates, wordpress-theming

[I have downloaded the free theme that can run to my Django server. I debug all things using static but the only front background image is not appearing on the server due to these problems in the console. Help me to get rid of this please.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7ynqT.png)

Comment: firstly, it would help to show the code and/or the structure of your site.  right now, it seems as if it's not finding ```static/styles/bootstrap4/bootstrap.min.js.map``` etc..  check the paths and your django site configuration.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, open up your console.

[image]

Then, uncheck the circled checkboxes

[image]

and then reload.

I faced this problem while developing in ReactJS but I hope this will translate into bootstrap as well. However, I don't think the failed sourcemap thing actually brings side-effects to your code.

**EDIT**

If you have Grammarly enabled, do this:

1. go to chrome://extensions

[image]

2. And then change the extension to be manually enabled

[image]

3. After that, every time to want to use Grammarly, you either have to manually enable it (image below) or add a list of sites where you want it to run automatically (not on the site which you're running the server on).

[image]

Comment: Devtools solved and now what about the first two errors?